# Javascript not working in JQuery loaded DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load pages into a div  , my question is i cant execute javascript code in page1.php..  How can i execute code when i load page in to div.. thanks for your help..

here is my codes

**index.php** :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#content").html('<img  class="loader" src="images/loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "load.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#content").html(data).show();
    });

}
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('page1');"> Button1 </a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('page2');"> Button2 </a>


<div id="content"></div>
```

**load.php** :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['contentVar']))
{
$contentVar = $_GET['contentVar'];  
    }else{
    $contentVar = $_POST['contentVar']; }
if ($contentVar == "page1") {
   include("page1.php");
} else if ($contentVar == "page2") {
   include("page2.php");
}
```

and example for **page1.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Data returned from Ajax is treated like plain text, so any Javascript within it is not executed by default. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314072/jquery-doesnt-execute-on-div-loaded-with-ajax) article.

Try using .load() instead of $.post() :

```
function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#content").html('<img  class="loader" src="images/loader.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "load.php";

    $("#content").load(url, {contentVar: cv});
}
```